# A proof about affine subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, problem-solving, proof-verification

Let $V$ be a vector space and $S$ a nonempty subset of $V$.  I want to show that $S$ is an affine subset (a translated subspace of the form $\{v\} +$ $U$, for $U$ a subspace of a vector space $V$ and fixed $v \in V$)  of $V$ **if and only if** (let's call this condition [*]) for every list of points $(x_1, ... , x_m)$ in $S$ and every list of scalars $(\lambda_1, ... , \lambda_m)$ in the field of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i = 1$, (then) the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i x_i \in S$.

This seems very easy to do in the first direction (starting with $S$ as an affine subset of $V$):

Suppose that $S$ is an affine subset of $V$.  This means that there exists some subspace $S'$ of $V$ such that $\{\{v\} + S' \} = S$ for some $v \in V$.  Checking if the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i x_i$ (remember that since $S$ is an affine subset of $V$, $x_i = v + s'_i$) lies in $S$ **with** condition [*]:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i (v + s'_i) = (\lambda_1 + ...+\lambda_m)v + (\lambda_1 x_1 + ...+\lambda_m x_m)$$

and we see that $(\lambda_1 + ...+\lambda_m)v = v$, and the RHS of the above equality is equivalent to $v + (\lambda_1 x_1 + ...+\lambda_m x_m) \in S$ since $S'$ is a subspace.

However, I do not see how to go in the other direction; I've been thinking about how to show that a nonempty subset $S \subseteq$ $V$, whose elements can be represented as linear combinations of elements in itself restricted by condition [*], is an affine subset of $V$ - but things are escaping me!  Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

**EDIT:** Specifically, I am trying to internally construct some subspace $S'$ of $V$ out of elements of $S$, because in order to show that $S$ is an affine subset of $V$, we have to show that everything in $S$ can assume the form $v + s', s' \in S'$.  So I tried defining every $s \in S$ in terms of $v$ and an arbitrary $s'_i$.  But where is the space-structure for $S'$ going to even come from?

Comment: What does $|\;V\;|$ mean?

Comment: @AlexBecker: Sorry about that! Thanks for alerting me! I meant it to denote the underlying set of the vector space $V$, but I just got rid of it entirely; I think it's probably clear enough without the bars.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

1) If $v \in S$ and $S$ has [*], it seems that it shouldn't be hard to show that $S - v$ has [*], and so we can assume WLOG that $0 \in S$. This means that we don't have to worry about how to shift our affine space, which is convenient.

2) If $0 \in S$, then given any $v \in S$, we can do something nice by applying [*] to the finite subset $\{0,v\}$. Once you notice what it is, it's easier to get the vector subspace structure on $S$.